# React dev tool doesn't show all components

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

In my react application, i have three component which are called like this. 
"APP -> Card -> Avatar". the code seems working. but, when i go to react dev tool tab in browser(components), only App and Card component is available. Avatar component is doesn't show up.

Attaching the details. 
App component..

```
  <Card
      name={"Beyonce"}
      imgURL={"119.jpg"}
      phone={"+123 456 789"}
      email={"b@beyonce.com"}
  />
```

Card component...

```
 <div className="top">
  <h2 className="name">{props.name}</h2>
  <Avatar source={props.imgURL} />
</div> 
<div className="bottom">
  <p className="info">{props.phone}</p>
  <p className="info">{props.email}</p>
</div>
```

Avatar component ..

```
function Avatar(props){ 
        return(
        <img className="circle-img" src={props.source} alt="avatar_img" />
       );
}
export default Avatar;
```

browser screenshoot -> [image]

Comment: Why do you have `<br>` after `<Card ...` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: edited. was a typing error.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, there is no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how come there is no error in the console because I believe this might be due to a JavaScript exception since you are trying to read `props.img.imgURL` which will throw `Uncaught TypeError` because it won't be possible to read property `imgURL` of undefined `props.img`.

Try modifying `Avatar` component as follows:

```js
function Avatar(props){ 
  return (
    <img className="circle-img" src={props.source} alt="avatar_img" />
  );
}
export default Avatar;
```

In other words, you have passed prop `source` to `Avatar` from card component however within `Avatar`, you are trying to read prop `img` which will be `undefined`.

Comment: hi, There was issue with the source version. somehow i paste the old code. but, the problem still persisted which got fixed when i reinstalled chrome.
Still, i am not sure about what happened. but, it is fixed now.

Comment: Oh, so you still have the same issue. Maybe try sandboxing your example somewhere online to see if you can still reproduce it.

Comment: Make sure you are not returning before `<Avatar .. />` I mean another return statement above.